# PostgreSQL how to delete duplicated values

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a table in my Postgres database where I forgot to insert a unique index. because of that index that i have now duplicated values. How to remove the duplicated values? I want to add a unique index on the fields translationset_Id and key.

[image]

Comment: Describe which values you want to remove.

Comment: For safe delete [refer this](http://donotforgetitmaster.blogspot.in/2014/08/delete-duplicate-data-from-redshift.html)

Comment: I want to remove the 2nd record, 4th record, 7th record, 11th record and 13th record. (see image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you only want to delete records which are duplicate with regard to the `translationset_id` column.  In this case, we can use Postgres' row number functionality to discern between duplicate rows, and then to delete those duplicates.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY translationset_id, key) AS rnum
    FROM yourTable t
)

DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE translationset_id IN (SELECT translationset_id FROM cte WHERE rnum > 1)
```

Comment: Where is the key column? "I have updated the prtScr"

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking for this:

`DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
FROM (SELECT id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY column1, column2, column3 ORDER BY id) AS rnum
FROM tablename) t
WHERE t.rnum > 1);`

Comment: This may not be completely correct.  It appears the partition should only be on the `translationset_id` and `key` columns, not others.

Comment: well this is like a blueprint that you can follow to solve your problem.I mostly use this for remembering the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from mytable
where exists (select 1
              from mytable t2
              where t2.name = mytable.name and
                    t2.address = mytable.address and
                    t2.zip = mytable.zip and
                    t2.ctid > mytable.ctid
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way to do this is below.

```
  DELETE  FROM
    table_name a
    USING table_name b
  WHERE
      a.id < b.id and
      a.same_column = b.same_column;
```